# Spring Boot 2.0.0.M1 error Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying out the new Spring-boot 2.0.0.M1. I initialized the project, just choosing the `Web` dependency, using https://start.spring.io/.

I opened this generated project in eclipse and I am getting following error while running `mvn clean install` on it:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener : org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:450)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:429)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getRunListeners(SpringApplication.java:415)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1278)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AopProxyUtils
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:446)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AopProxyUtils
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.addApplicationListener(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.<init>(EventPublishingRunListener.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:145)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Did anyone face similar issue? Please help.

Comment: I doubt this is the output of `mvn clean install` as it is running the application. A `mvn clean install` wouldn't do that. Unless you modified the pom. Before doing a build try `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` to clean the dependencies and have them re downloaded.

Comment: Yeah, I did that and solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The AutoProxyUtils class is available into org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy package instead of org.springframework.aop.framework package. Check the correct version of spring-aop library is available in classpath. However, it seems that it is bug of the framework.

I have got another work around for this,

exclude the spring-aop from boot dependency like

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

and add spring-aop separately with new version

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I Have faced the same issue, I have removed the springaop folder from .m2 ( Maven repository) and build it. It was working fine now

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with spring boot 1.5.4.RELEASE project.I am using Amazon S3 dependencies for the project. I followed above steps and provided exclusions and added aop dependency but it did not resolved the issue. When I changed the spring boot version from 1.5.4.RELEASE to 1.5.6.RELEASE, it was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Include spring-aop dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```